# SilverStripe 3.6.1 unable to load TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, silverstripe

A fresh installation of SilverStripe is not able to load TinyMCE correctly because the path to some files is not correct, see screenshot: https://www.imgpaste.net/image/Ds9Ve

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Please provide the version you've just installed. In itself this question is probably not appropriate for Stackoverflow. If you believe it's a core problem you could [open an issue](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues) on the framework so it can be treated as a core bug

Comment: No,  think it's a configuration issue. But I don't get it. Happens the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by gzip compression on the server clashing with the TinyMCE code used by `HTMLEditorield`.

To disable gzip on our `HTMLEditorield` we can put the following in our `config.yml` file:

```yml
HtmlEditorField:
  use_gzip: false
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a ton!