# TinyMCE not loading Silverstripe 3.6.2 or 4 (beta 3)

Tags: javascript, tinymce, content-management-system, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I installed SilverStripe on my shared server and everything went fine, requirements met, etc.

Right after the install, I deleted the install files and tried to edit my new site. Everything works fine in the back-end except when I want to edit a page. Here's an idea of what I get :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGy9p.jpg

I don't bother with .map files not loading since I looked on the SS official demo site and it fails to load to same files. So the problem seems to come with the tinymce-cms-17db2fb8cf.js file. However I can't see what's wrong with it... The file's there and permissions are OK...

The URL of this site is http://www.steveforest.space/

Thanks

Comment: When you say you deleted the install files, which files do you mean? Also how are you deploying your site to the server?

Comment: It is an automated process after the installation. In fact, it only deletes the 'install.php' file that allow the initial setup of the CMS. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by ''deploy''... I created a subdomain, a MySQL db and transfered SS files manually on the server since I can't use Composer (I'm on a shared server with limited access, I can use SSH but don't have enough privileges to install stuff). The old fashionned way to install SS on a server like I did in the past.

Comment: I see. SS4 relies on composer for installation, so while it may work I wouldn't guarantee it will continue to. You can install composer simply with a wget/apt-get/curl command, you don't need system privileges

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658301/silverstripe-3-6-1-unable-to-load-tinymce

Comment: Yes and no luck with that. @Robbie Averill Tried to install via composer. OK for 3.6.2 but same problem with 4.0 beta 3. Don't think using Composer is trivial since both installation method is described in SS installation tutorial. I prefer 4.0 -- almost all add-ons are now 4.0 ready.

Comment: For me that strikes as a permission issue: Either PHP cant write to the assets folder or apache (or ngingx) cant read the file. If the file is present and the content is right then PHP has write permission but the webserver can't serve the asset.

Comment: Can you compare the user/group of the js file. If you just upload a file manually to the assets folder > they work right?

Comment: Same user/group as any other file of the CMS. File permission 644, but don't work with even if I give it full privileges. The file is generated in the installation process of the CMS, so I cannot manually upload it ; even the filename is randomly generated.

Comment: New URL : www.steveforest.space

Comment: @SteveForest I ment to do that as a test. And its not generated by the install process it's more likely to be generated for caching purposes by tynymc or silversripe. The point was to see if PHP created files work right compared to a manually  uploaded file.

Comment: but the facts are: the file is created under the and if you view the file directly on the server it has content? If so then the webserver can't access the file or the PATH to the file is wrong. If PHP created the _tinymce folder > does that have correct user/permission > if you move the generated file up one folder can the browser display the js file then? Just thest the JS files serving for now under the assets folder for now

Answer (score 1):

> _config.php

Config::inst()->update('HtmlEditorField', 'use_gzip', false);

Comment: It gives me a server error. SS4 seems to prefer config.yml file for site settings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658301/silverstripe-3-6-1-unable-to-load-tinymce but no luck with that one either.